# Bash script syntax

Tags: bash

I was trying to write a bash script. This is the code I've managed to write.

```
#!/bin/bash


RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

CurrentBranch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
printf("${RED}$CurrentBranch${NC}")
```

I am storing the current branch value in a variable and trying to print it in red colour, but I'm getting the following error.

Comment: Try the printf without the parantheses: `printf "${RED}$CurrentBranch${NC}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

printf doesn't use parentheses. Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash


RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

CurrentBranch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
printf "${RED}$CurrentBranch${NC}"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be working:

```
#!/bin/bash


RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

CurrentBranch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
printf "${RED}$CurrentBranch${NC}"
```

There is no need for parentheses in printf.